# Accessing the params hash for year and month rails and using in helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I took some php code and turned it into a calendar with a helper to make a simple calendar.

I got my data from inside the helper:

```
 def calendar_maker
 a = Time.now
 b = a.month
 d = a.year
 h = Time.gm(d,b,1) #first day of month
```

Now I want to try and do it with parameters within my method

```
 #from the helper file
 def calendar_maker(year, month)
 a = Time.now
 b = month
 c = year
 h = Time.gm(d,b,1) #first day of month

#from my html.erb file
<%= @month %> and <%= @year %>
<%= params["month"] %><br />
<%= params["action"] %><br />
<%= params["year"] %><br />
<%= calendar_maker( @year, @month) %>

#from controller file
def calendar
  @month = params[:month]
  @year = params[:year]
end
```

Anyways mistakes were made and not finding documentation anywhere or not looking in the right place.  How do I get this to work with my params hash using instance variables @month and @year from the controller and my local parameters in my calendar_maker method year and month. Do I just grab the value from the params hash and assign it directly to the instance variable in my helper or controller? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: updated my question to be more descriptive sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this tagged as Rails and there's erb, so I'll assume that's true. You should look at all the gee-whizzy date helpers Rails has to offer. You just don't have to do this stuff.

Specifically, `beginning_of_month` completely replaces your `calendar_maker` stuff, if I understand it correctly. So you could do `Date.today.beginning_of_month` to replace your helper.

If you have a controller action called `#calendar` and a view file called `html.erb`, your view file will not, by default, be rendered as it doesn't follow the correct naming convention. You'd want to name the erb file `calendar.html.erb`. You might have done this and truncated the name in your code example.

If you could be more specific about what exactly is going wrong, you will get more helpful feedback. What errors are you seeing? What did you get as opposed to what you expected to get. That kind of thing.

Oh, and Rails has `date_select` and `datetime_select` if you are just looking for a quick way to get that information into a form.